# How to do aggregation using match and lookup operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

How to include aggregation in if condition ,do I need to use project or condition method in if condition above as well catalogue populate. I need to get the data from the mongo dB in the same order as video Ids array but it's coming in a different order so I decided to use aggregation to get the video in a proper order as in the video Ids array. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
let filter = {$match:{
        customerId: customerId,
        _id: {
          $in: _.map(videoIds, id => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)) || []
        },
        _isDeleted: false,
        isActive: true
      },
      $lookup:{
        from:'catalogues',
        localField:'_isDeleted',
        foreignField:'_id',
        as:false
      
    }
    }

      if (!req.isLocationWhitelisted) {
        if (req._countryCode) {
          $or=
          filter.$match['languages.country'] = {
            $in: req._countryCode
          }
          filter.$lookup['languages.country'] = {
            $in: req._countryCode
          }
        ,
        filter.$match['languages.country.141'] = { $exists: true }
        filter.$lookup['languages.country.141'] = { $exists: true }
        }
      }
      
      let videoList = await Video.aggregate(filter);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly create a mongoplayground with sample data, attempted query to understand better

Comment: aggregate take an array of pipeline not an object

Comment: Please edit your question to include 1 or 2 examples of docs in the collection and the desired target output.   Optionally you can set it up in mongoplayground but the examples need to be searchable here on SO.